# creating numpy ndarrays from existing ndarrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When I create a numpy array, the shape usually works out different to what I anticipate.  I don't know what I'm getting wrong, please point me in the right direction.

For example:

```
theta = np.random.rand(n , 1)*2 *np.pi 
theta.round(3)
Out[283]: 
array([[ 0.827],
       [ 0.951],
       [ 5.371],
       [ 0.889]])
```

From theta I want to create an array with the vector components for the velocity (nx2 array)...  I tried several, but always got the wrong shape, which works if I reshape it, but surely I should be able to get straight there.

velocity = array of x and y, where x = v * cos(theta) and y = v * sin(theta)

```
velocity.reshape(n, 2)
Out[281]: 
array([[ 1.16966072, -0.22284058],
       [-0.35621286,  0.7848923 ],
       [ 0.26813019, -1.17912768],
       [-1.14591116,  0.90771365]])
```

I tried several ways to build the array.  Clearly I've got this close, but not quite right.

```
velocity = np.array((np.cos(theta) * v, np.sin(theta)*v), dtype=float)

velocity
Out[279]: 
array([[[ 1.16966072],
        [-0.22284058],
        [-0.35621286],
        [ 0.7848923 ]],

       [[ 0.26813019],
        [-1.17912768],
        [-1.14591116],
        [ 0.90771365]]])

velocity.shape
Out[280]: (2, 4, 1)
```

velocity = np.array([[np.cos(theta) * v], [np.sin(theta)*v]], dtype=float)

```
velocity
Out[274]: 
array([[[[ 1.16966072],
         [-0.22284058],
         [-0.35621286],
         [ 0.7848923 ]]],


       [[[ 0.26813019],
         [-1.17912768],
         [-1.14591116],
         [ 0.90771365]]]])

velocity.shape
Out[275]: (2, 1, 4, 1)


velocity = np.dstack((np.cos(theta) * v, np.sin(theta)*v))

velocity
Out[268]: 
array([[[ 1.16966072,  0.26813019]],

       [[-0.22284058, -1.17912768]],

       [[-0.35621286, -1.14591116]],

       [[ 0.7848923 ,  0.90771365]]])

velocity.shape
Out[269]: (4, 1, 2)
```

Comment: What should be the output exactly?

Comment: velocity.reshape(n, 2) .. semantically an array of the x and y components of the velocity given the polar coordinates v and theta.

Comment: How about `np.c_[np.cos(theta)*v, np.sin(theta)*v]`?

Comment: How does `v` look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`theta` is `(n,1)`

`np.array([theta, theta])` is `(2, n, 1)`.  That is, `np.array` joins the 2 component arrays along a new axis, hence the initial 2.

`np.array([[theta], [theta]])` wraps each `theta` in a []`, so each is`(1,n,1)`, and together`(2,1,n,1)`.

If you want (n,2), you need to concatenate on the 2nd axis.  For example:

```
velocity = np.concatenate([np.cos(theta) * v, np.sin(theta)*v], axis=1)
```

`hstack` and `column_stack` would also do this, as well as the `c_`.

If you had created `theta` as `(n,)` (1d instead of 2), `stack` could have been used to join them on a new 2nd axis:

```
velocity = np.stack([np.cos(theta) * v, np.sin(theta)*v], axis=1)
```

Or `np.array([...]).T`, i.e. make a (2,n) and transpose it.

There are lots of ways joining two `n` element arrays into a (n,2) array.  Even `np.squeeze(np.array(....)).T`, removing the 1 from the (2,n,1).

Comment: Thanks.  A lot to digest.  How would I create theta as (n,)?

Comment: @BlueShrapnel; `How would I create theta as (n,)?`, `theta` in your post **does** have a shape of (n,1).

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj, that's helped me clear my thinking, I didn't realise I was creating 2d arrays by specifying the other was 1.  In maths a nx1 array is just a column on n rows.  theta = np.random(n)